# Responsive bootstrap grid with SVG filling div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm trying to create a 3 column bootstrap grid, with an SVG in the center column that responsively fills it's div like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rjmcy54t/

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 p-0 bg-warning">
  <div class="row no-gutters h-25">
    <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info">Left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="Blue"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The SVG overflows and expands it's div. I read that this is because the divs height is set to 100% and it doesn't have a  height to give to the SVG.

I tried wrapping the SVG in a div with height 25vh:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqk14e98/

```
  <div class="container-fluid h-100 p-0 bg-warning">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-25">
      <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info">Left</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success">
        <div style="height:25vh">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <rect width="100" height="100" fill="Blue"></rect>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 bg-info">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This seems to give me the correct behavior. Is it the best way? What is the correct way to write this without using hardcoded pixel values?